# Problems invoking a method with a BigInteger parameter

Tags: java, biginteger

I faced trouble and I can't do anything with that. I wonder how may I call this method?

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    return result;
}
```

For var=1, I got it, I wrote following:

```
BigInteger kk = BigInteger.ONE;
System.out.println(factorial(kk));
```

but, I confused how to count 61!, for instance.

Comment: I understood the question by reading the answer first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
BigInteger kk = BigInteger.ONE
System.out.println(factorial(kk));
```

To

```
BigInteger kk=new BigInteger("61");
System.out.println(factorial(kk));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 BigInteger kk = new BigInteger("61");
 System.out.println(factorial(kk));
```

Answer (score 3):

Java also has a [static factory method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29):

```
BigInteger kk = BigInteger.valueOf(61L);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BigInteger kk = new BigInteger("61");
System.out.println(factorial(kk));
```

The API is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: If you are not sure how to construct an object, first port of call is to read the API for that object and read the constructor section

Comment: yahoo, I got it!) I've found the answer there. BigInteger(String val) 
          Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

Comment: Good to hear, thats all I did when I saw your question :)